# Transfer files from local machine to remote server with the php script residing on remote server

Tags: php, ftp, file-transfer

Is it possible to transfer a file from local machine to a remote server if the php script (say using ftp functions ) resides on a remote server?. I heard it might take to set up the local machine as a FTP server and the local machine should have a static IP address.

I am looking for directions as to how to set up the local machine to be a ftp server?., or is there any other way with php other than the form file upload($_FILES) thing ?.

Would appreciate any help. Thanks!.

Comment: The case is that there is going to be a few tens of files to be uploaded every time, hence trying to avoid $_FILES.

Comment: What is your local machine's operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP will work, but:

- If the server and the client are on the same network, you can use a network share.  Going this route, you can use the normal filesystem functions available in PHP ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)).  Just use the network name and share path, flip the slashes to forward: "//servername/path/to/share"  [Here is a tutorial on setting up a network share](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsxpnetworking/ht/sharewinxpfiles.htm), assuming Windows is the client OS.
- If network share is out of the question, you can set up a local FTP server. [Here is a Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/130806/how-to-set-up-a-home-ftp-server) on how to set this up, assuming you have a Windows OS. There are similar tutorials for Mac and *nix, there are so many you'd have to *try* NOT to find them on Google. :)  There are many other routes to set up the FTP server, it isn't that important which server you use, **just make sure you aren't leaving yourself wide open to the internet**.  After you set up the local FTP server, use [PHP's FTP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) to connect from the server to your local machine.

It really is a better route to use the network share if you can, but of course that isn't an option if the server is not in your local network.

Answer (score 0):

What is your local machine's operating system? If it's windows I would recommend [FileZilla FTP Server](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server). Here is a guide [how to install and setup FileZilla FTP server](http://lifehacker.com/339887/build-a-home-ftp-server-with-filezilla).