# Move file to external server

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to move a PDF file from a local server to an external server of which I know the IP address. I'm generating the PDF file in a local folder, reading it and then I need to move it. Here's my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ''.DOCS_ARCHIVE_PATH.'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
$fh_res = fopen(DOCS_TEMP_ARCHIVE_PATH.$name, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh_res);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_path_str));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_response_res = curl_exec ($ch);
fclose($fh_res);
```

The response of Curl is `405 method not allowed`

`DOCS_TEMP_ARCHIVE_PATH` is `/mtn/some/folder/`

`DOCS_ARCHIVE_PATH` is `http://192.1.x.x/final/folder`

I've also tried to remove the `http` and `$curl_response_res` is completely empty.

Comment: Do you have FTP enabled in the remote server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387385/transfer-files-from-local-machine-to-remote-server-with-the-php-script-residing

Comment: FTP isn't working, I've already saw the question posted by jewelhuq and i've also read a lot of resource here and around the web. There's any other possible solution?